# How to play more then one video in an activity at same time

Tags: android

I want to play four video in same activity in android is there any way to do it.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create more than one video view, and play different video in each one.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView video1 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview1);
    VideoView video2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview2);
    // set paths and play each one
}
```

Comment: What does your layout file look like?